# Animacion en C, con Graphics.h

Tags: c, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo una animacion de tarea, a base de imagenes con putpixel , utilizo setvisualpage, y setactivepage para el parpadeo que tiene a la hora de mostrar y quitar una imagen. El caso es que ahora quiero que la animación se mueva más rápido, habrá una forma de hacerlo? con delay la retraso pero no sé si hay una función o manera que me permita que la animación vea fluida.

```
#include<winbgim.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<gotoxy.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void fotograma(int alto, int ancho);
void Llenar(int alto, int ancho);
void Archivo(int cont);
void Bienvenida();

FILE *archivo;

struct Pixeles
{
    int Rojo;
    int Verde;
    int Azul;   
}RGB[2000];

struct Imagen
{
    struct Pixeles RGB[2000];
}foto[2000];

int main()
{

int cont, page=0;
system("color f4");
initwindow(720,480);
setbkcolor(15);
clearviewport();
Bienvenida();
for(int ciclo=0;ciclo<10;ciclo++)
{
    for(cont=1;cont<7;cont++)
    {
        setactivepage(0);
        setvisualpage(1);
        cleardevice();
        Archivo(cont);
    }
}
closegraph();
}
void Bienvenida()
{
    setcolor(BLACK);
    settextstyle(2,0,8);
    outtextxy(40,40,"H");Beep(200,100);delay(500);outtextxy(70,40,"O");Beep(200,100);delay(500);
    outtextxy(100,40,"L");Beep(200,100);delay(500);outtextxy(130,40,"A");Beep(200,100);delay(500);
}
void Archivo(int cont)
{
    int  alto=0, ancho=0, aux=0;
    char nombre[20];
    switch(cont)
    {
    case 1:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto1.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;  
    case 2:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto2.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;
    case 3:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto3.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;
    case 4:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto4.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;
    case 5:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto5.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;
    case 6:
            strcpy(nombre,"foto6.txt");     fflush(stdin);      break;
    }
    archivo=fopen(nombre,"r");
        if(archivo==NULL)
        {
            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(20,20);printf("ERROR AL CREAR EL ARCHIVO");
            system("pause");
            return;
        }
    setcolor(BLACK);
    settextstyle(11,0,1);
    //outtextxy(2,690,"¡¡ARCHIVO DE TEXTO ABIERTO CON EXITO!!");
    fscanf(archivo,"%d %d",&alto,&ancho);
    fscanf(archivo,"%d",&aux);
    Llenar(alto, ancho);
}
void Llenar(int alto, int ancho)
{   
    for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<alto;j++)
        {
            int auxR=0, auxG=0,auxB=0;
            fscanf(archivo,"%d %d %d",&auxR,&auxG,&auxB);
            foto[j].RGB[i].Azul=auxB; foto[j].RGB[i].Rojo=auxR; foto[j].RGB[i].Verde=auxG;
        }
    }
    fotograma(alto,ancho);
}
void fotograma(int alto, int ancho)
{   
    for(int i=0;i<ancho;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<alto;j++)
        {
        putpixel(j+20,i+20,COLOR(foto[j].RGB[i].Rojo,foto[j].RGB[i].Verde,foto[j].RGB[i].Azul));
        }
    }
fclose(archivo);
}
```

Comment: Si deseas que te ayudemos debes mostrar un [mcve]

Comment: listo, alli el codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para controlar cómo se muestra un gráfico por pantalla primero debes entender el concepto de [Fotogramas por segundo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotogramas_por_segundo), copio de la wikipedia:

> **Fotogramas por segundo**, también llamada **tasa de refresco**, **imágenes por segundo**, **cuadros por segundo**, FPS (del inglés «frames per second») o **framerate**, es la velocidad (tasa) a la cual un dispositivo muestra imágenes llamadas cuadros o [fotogramas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fotograma).

Es decir, el refresco de los gráficos en pantalla estará ligado a la velocidad que tu programa refresque los datos visuales.

#### Propuesta.

Olvida `delay`, y haz que tus imágenes se pinten siempre, la imagen a pintar dependerá de la animación que estés pintando, para controlarlo crea un objeto `animacion` que almacene el recuento de fotogramas, su velocidad de refresco y el momento en que la animación se inició:

```
typedef struct animacion
{
    unsigned fotogramas;
    unsigned refresco;
    clock_t inicio;
};
```

Con este objeto animación podrás calcular qué fotograma debes pintar dependiendo del momento en que se inició la animación. Por ejemplo, una animación de 8 fotogramas a un fotograma cada dos segundos tendría un objeto `animacion` así:

```
struct animacion a;
a.fotogramas = 8;
a.refresco = 2000; // tiempo expresado en milisegundos
a.inicio = clock();
```

Para calcular en qué fotograma de la animación estás, lo harás en base a cuándo la animación empezó:

```
int fotograma_actual(struct animacion *p_animacion)
{
    long tiempo_transcurrido = clock() - p_animacion->inicio();
    return (int)tiempo_transcurrido / p_animacion->refresco;
}
```

La función `fotograma_actual` hace una división entera entre el tiempo transcurrido desde el inicio de la animación y la frecuencia de refresco de la misma, así siguiendo nuestro ejemplo:

- Si han transcurrido 0,5 segundos desde el inicio de la animación, el fotograma es `500 / 2000` que es `0` (el primer fotograma).
- Si han transcurrido 1,367 segundos desde el inicio de la animación, el fotograma es `1367 / 2000` que es `0` (el primer fotograma).
- Si han transcurrido 3,442 segundos desde el inicio de la animación, el fotograma es `3442 / 2000` que es `1` (el segundo fotograma).
- Si han transcurrido 13 segundos desde el inicio de la animación, el fotograma es `13000 / 2000` que es `6` (el séptimo fotograma).
- Si han transcurrido 57,31 segundos desde el inicio de la animación, el fotograma es `57310 / 2000` que es `28` (el vigésimo noveno fotograma).

Como puedes observar, podemos obtener resultados más allá de los fotogramas permitidos por la animación, dependerá de ti decidir que hacer en esos casos, si el fotograma es mayor a los fotogramas de la animación debes considerar la animación acabada, pero si quieres mostrar la animación en bucle puedes quedarte con el residuo de dividir el fotograma obtenido por el número de fotogramas:

```
struct animacion a;
a.fotogramas = 8;
a.refresco = 2000; // tiempo expresado en milisegundos
a.inicio = clock();

while(1)
{
    int fotograma = fotograma_actual(&a) % a.fotogramas;
    // pintar fotograma
}
```

Comment: wow, muchas gracias, no tenia idea de ese metodo, practicaré en base a lo que me dijiste.